# My custom icon doesn't appear in the 'local' push notification (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have created a new Ionic app and setup the cordova local notifications plugin to have notifications run in the background without the need for an external server such as Google Cloud Messaging using this plugin.
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Everything seems to work but for some reason the icon shown in the notification isn't the one that I am setting in the js below - can anyone suggest what is wrong - it does show an icon, (an alarm bell) but it isn't the one that have I specified.

```
// within my $ionicPlatform.ready
    $scope.scheduleSingleNotification = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Warning',
        text: 'My first local notification this will stick!',
        icon: '../img/github-icon.png'
      }).then(function (result) {
        console.log('Notification #1 triggered');
      });
    };
```

Comment: Icon should be present in all sizes 48 × 48 (mdpi) 72 × 72 (hdpi) 96 × 96 (xhdpi) 144 × 144 (xxhdpi) 192 × 192 (xxxhdpi) 512 × 512

Comment: I can't see how that is implemented using this plugin as it only asks for a single icon parameter

Comment: Bro an up vote thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem few months back but than i have given a hit and trial an it worked for

create the icons of all sizes and copy them to /platforms/android/res/
and respective folders of sizes i hope that will solve problem

An always give the path of img respect to your index file not the file in which your are coding but to the main file in which it's included

Comment: Thanks Siddharth - the documentation for the plugin is good but the icon stuff isn't quite right - i did what you said and got it working when removing the extension (and removed the dash it doesn't like those).

e.g icon: 'yourfile'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the icon has a white or transparent background. If you take a look at the documentation:

[Android notifications](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/design/patterns/notifications.html)

```
icons should only be a white-on-transparent background image.
```

Comment: this is the image i tried to use - http://sciactive.com/pnotify/includes/github-icon.png